# Guardian.Plug.EnsurePermissions is unrecognized

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, guardian

I am attempting to implement permissions-based security in my Phoenix app using Guardian. I've found examples online, but when I try to implement them, I can't get past this error:

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Guardian.Plug.EnsurePermissions.init/1 is undefined (module Guardian.Plug.EnsurePermissions is not available)
```

I have Guardian installed an basic authentication working. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. EnsurePermissions was deprecated, in case anyone else struggles with this.

https://hexdocs.pm/guardian/upgrading-v1.0.html